# Is there a way to bind hotkey that moves camera to last alert point on map?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a way to bind hotkey that moves camera to last alert point on map ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, by default, <kbd>Space</kbd> will move the camera to the last alert.

Comment: While this answer is correct, I'd advise against using this method generally. What if just as you push space, you get a different alert? Then you end up being in the wrong spot and wasting time. Set Camera Locations for important places, such as your main, nat and third. You can double tap control groups for most other regions of interest, otherwise just click on the map.